# How to leave an approval comment in github

Tags: github, pull-request

I had a project and I made a repo for that on github. I made two different branches then I did my development. Now I want to pull my second branch, but it says that I need an approval, [one approving review is enough] and now the problem is that I don't know how to do that.

Also if you know how to turn off safe-sittings of github please tell me how.

Comment: Nothing in this question involves Git. Pull requests and the behavior of the GitHub web site are features of GitHub alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the GitHub CLI gh, assuming you are allowed to approve a PR, you can use [`gh pr review`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_review)

```bash
# approve the pull request of the current branch
$ gh pr review --approve
```

This is faster than:

1. Go to the issue on GitHub that you want to approve.
2. Scroll down to the "Reviews" section and click on the "Add your review" button.
3. In the "Review changes" section, select the "Approve" option from the drop-down menu.
   If you want, you can add comments or feedback in the "Leave a comment" section.
4. Click on the "Submit review" button to submit your approval.